# Failed to load .js resource

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, javascript, webpage

**Hello, using "Inspect the element" function on Google Crome browser, on almost every site I have the same error**

```
Failed to load resource http://content.magnipic.info/shopping/ppapp.js
```

one of this website is http://pretesti.ge

The bigger problem is that when I open one of the pages from http://proprofs.com to edit my online quizes as usual black foreground appears (while loading questions, with opacity about 20%) and wont disapear when the page is loaded. I can scroll, but cant click and open anything under that dark layer. I tried on the other computer the same thing and it just worked, but not on mine (**I tried both Firefox and Chrome**). Element Inspector says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16205031744365114719' of undefined jquery.min.js:16
13
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16205031744365114719' of undefined jquery.min.js:16
f.extend.data jquery.min.js:16
f.extend._data jquery.min.js:16
f.event.handle jquery.min.js:17
i.handle.k jquery.min.js:16
Failed to load resource http://content.magnipic.info/shopping/ppapp.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16205031744365114719' of undefined jquery.min.js:16
f.extend.data jquery.min.js:16
f.extend._data jquery.min.js:16
f.event.handle jquery.min.js:17
i.handle.k jquery.min.js:16
```

I think it might be a spying program on my pc that shows me some adds which generally shouldn't appear, and when I click sometimes the nonusual add opens. (this program might be the reason).
I whould like to get a help to disapear the dark layer uppon the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at http://content.magnipic.info/shopping/ppapp.js, well tried to load it but it didn't.  Then I looked at simply: http://content.magnipic.info/

And my virus software says:

Trend Micro has confirmed that this website can transmit malicious software or has been involved in online scams or fraud.

Hope this helps you a little.

Answer (score 1):

This domain has expired and so you cannot get any files from this site. I tried loading the sites you mentioned and they worked just fine. Maybe you have some toolbars or extensions. Try disabling/uninstalling those.

You can use this: [Click to Remove Element](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-to-remove-element/jcgpghgjhhahcefnfpbncdmhhddedhnk?hl=en) for chrome.